# How to serialize a Kotlin Set to a JSON object whose values are empty objects?

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I would like to make a Kotlin class serializable using Kotlin serialization.

The class is very simple, something like this:

```kotlin
@Serializable(with = CustomSerializer::class)
data class MyObject(val keys: Set<String>)
```

Now, I need the serialization format to be a JSON object where the keys are given by the `Set<String>` and the values are always empty JSON objects.

Example:

```kotlin
val example = MyObject(setOf("abc", "def"))
```

Should serialize to:

```json
{ "abc": {}, "def": {} }
```

> The reason is that this object is being sent to an API where that's how they want the JSON to look like... the empty objects could contain some directives but I don't want or need to use those.

Having trouble doing that by just [reading the documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md).

Answer (score 1):

I've found one way to do it... and it seems simple enough!

I realized that I can get a serializer of empty Objects almost for free with this:

```kotlin
@Serializable
private object EmptyMap
```

Now, I can write a custom serializer in a straightforward way:

```kotlin
object MyObjectSerializer : KSerializer<MyObject> {
    private val _delegate = MapSerializer(String.serializer(), EmptyMap.serializer())

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = _delegate.descriptor

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: MyObject) {
        val data = value.keys.associateWith { EmptyMap }
        encoder.encodeSerializableValue(_delegate, data)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): MyObject {
        val value = decoder.decodeSerializableValue(_delegate)
        return MyObject(value.keys)
    }

}
```

Now all that's left to do is to apply the serializer on the type, which can be done with:

```
@Serializer(with = MyObjectSerializer)
data class MyObject(val keys: Set<String>)
```

Running `Json.encodeToString(example)` on the examples works perfectly.